# R: forming all consecutive combinations from a vector

Tags: r, combinations, combinatorics

Suppose I have a vector like this:

```
a<-c(1,2,3,4)
```

How do I get all consecutive combinations from it like:

```
1,2,3,4
2,3,4,1
3,4,1,2
4,1,2,3
```

but nothing else?
Unfortunately my vector is much larger so doing it by hand would cost too much time.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `matrix`

```
 matrix(a, ncol=4, nrow=5)[1:4,]
 #       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    1    2    3    4
 #[2,]    2    3    4    1
 #[3,]    3    4    1    2
 #[4,]    4    1    2    3
```

We can generalize the above as

```
 n <- length(a)
 matrix(a, ncol=n, nrow=n+1)[seq(n),]
```

Comment: Nice. Maybe generalize further